# Why is is harder to type parentheses () than square brackets [] on a standard keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

Is there a particular reason why you need to use the shift key to type a parenthesis - `(` or `)` - whereas you do not for a square bracket - `[` or `]`, on a standard QWERTY keyboard? The parenthesis is a much more common symbol in writing (and probably programming, too). Is it some kind of historical thing?

Comment: If it really bugs you, then you could modify your key mappings, keep in mind that you will drive anyone else using your keyboard insane.

Comment: @Zoredache it doesn't bug me, I was just interested from an "interface" perspective why it was the case. Inexplicably everyone else decided this factual question was "likely to solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion".

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's historical.  Typewriters had the parentheses as Shift-9 and Shift-8 for decades before computers.  There were no square bracket keys (there also wasn't a key for the number 1 on most keyboards -- use used a lower-case "L").  When computer keyboards were invented, they copied typewriters so as not to require keypunchers to learn a new system.

Later, the bracket keys were added.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Somehow I forgot typewriters originally used the keyboard we have now.